# UIButton TouchUpInside event count on specific ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, objective-c-blocks

I have some 10 `UIButtons` in a `UIViewController`. What I want to achieve is: when a user taps any 4 buttons (it can be 4 different buttons or 2 buttons but tapped total 4 times), it fires a particular method. The method should triggered right after 4th **TouchUpInside** event called, no matter with 4 different buttons or less. It should count the **TouchUpInside** from several buttons and fire a method.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a simple **tap counter**!

First create a `integer` in the header and then create an `IBAction` which you assign every button to.

The `IBAction` should contain something like this:

```
-(IBAction)BtnTapped:(id)sender {

    [self tappedBtn];
    [self checkNumber];
}
```

if you are not using IB, then just paste this line of code in your viewDidLoad:

```
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to get the number of touches higher:

```
-(void)tappedEgg{
//currentValue is an int declared in the header file (look below)
    currentValue = currentValue +1;
    NSLog(@"%i",currentValue);

}
```

And to check the Number:

```
-(void)checkNumber{

    if (currentValue == 4) {
        NSLog(@"Reached 4");
        //Put in your action
    }
}
```

in the header file below the `#import` do:

```
int currentValue;
```

---

That should do it!

Greetings!

Comment: @farisolusa dont forget to upvote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an int ivar to your view controller, and increment it by 1 every time a button is tapped. Also, in the tap handlers, check the current count, and if it's equal to 4, call your method.

Comment: Can you please explain it with a sample code?